# Setting up an additonal CXFServlet with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cxf

I am currently trying to get a CXF Servlet to run along side the regular Web MVC Servlet. My CXF Servlet defines multiple endpoints namely:

- `/api/v1/*`
- `/soap/v2/*`
- `/internal-api/v1/*`

I also want the `DispatcherServlet` for Spring MVC to run under `/api/v2/*`

When I configure:

```
 @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> cxfServlet() {
        final ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> cxfServletServletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new CXFServlet(), "/*");
        return cxfServletServletRegistrationBean;
    }
```

everything about CXF works, but no more `@Controller` in the spring boot app are reachable anymore.(well of course now everything is directed to the cxfservlet)

But when I configure:

```
 @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> cxfServlet() {
        final ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> cxfServletServletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new CXFServlet(), "/api/v1/*");
        return cxfServletServletRegistrationBean;
    }
```

the endpoints of cxf are only reachable now if I use an url such as this `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/api/v1/test`.

How can I configure the spring boot app, so `/api/v2/*` is directed to the spring mvc servlet and the cxf servlet still works like described above?

Comment: It just might be that the `ServletRegistrationBean` also works for a `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: I already tried that... the `/*` url mapping of the cxf servlet still catches everything and nothing goes to the dispatcher servlet. the cxf servlet just responds no service found for urls that should be mapped to a `@Controller`

Comment: You tried what? You tried the `CXFServlet` if you register the `DispatcherServlet` for the proper ULR prefix, the reuqests will be properly routed.

Answer (score 1):

Registering a dispatcher servlet manually instead of letting spring boot autoconfiguration do it fixed the issue:

```
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> cxfServlet() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new CXFServlet(), "/*");
    }

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        dispatcherServlet.setThreadContextInheritable(true);
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        return dispatcherServlet;
    }

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
        DispatcherServletRegistrationBean registration = new DispatcherServletRegistrationBean(
                dispatcherServlet(),
                "/api/v2/*"
        );
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(0);
        registration.setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);
        return registration;
    }
}
```

Note that registering the cxf servlet under anything but `/*` will ruin the routes of the cxf servlet.